# Save drawing on Jpanel as image

Tags: java, image, swing, applet

I am developing a drawing program using java socket. Multiple users can draw and save it as jpeg. Currently my save image function only save a blank canvas. It cannot save the co-ordinates drawn.

I am sharing part of my code below. =)

I did not use paint or paintComponent for my Canvas class because of the use java socket i am experiencing sending coordinate errors. Instead i am using massDraw().

```
    class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private int x, y;
    private float x2, y2;

    public Canvas() {
        super();
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void massDraw(int px, int py, int x, int y, int red, int green,
            int blue, int size) {
        Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHints(myBrush);

        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));
        g2d.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
        g.drawLine(px, py, x, y);

    }


}// end Canvas class
```

SaveJpegOP class

```
class saveJpegOP implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Ask for file name
        String str = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog(null, "Enter File Name : ");
        // save as jpeg
           BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(canvas.getSize().width, canvas.getSize().height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
           canvas.paint(bufImage.createGraphics());  



        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufImage, "jpg", new File(str + ".jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you call `massDraw`? What is the variable `canvas`? You should never call `getGraphics()`, this always leads to the problems you describe. I can absolutely not understand why you can't override `paintComponent`

Comment: 1. massDraw is called at the other public class(Client) file.When Client receive the coordinate it will draw the points on the canvas of the other users.

Comment: 2. canvas varible is from Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

Comment: override paintComponent() and use the Graphics parameter of that method. When you want the component to be refreshed/repainted: call `repaint()`

Comment: Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It is impossible to guess that you have other classes, that perform other method invocations, etc... Anyway, when you call `canvas.paint`, does it goes through your massDraw method? If not, then there is your problem.

Comment: _2. canvas varible is from Canvas canvas = new Canvas();_ ??? You are already inside a `Canvas`. So you are referencing a `Canvas` instance from another `Canvas` instance? Shouldn't you use `this` instead? You should anyway never call `getGraphics()`, this is just looking for troubles and it does not make any sense.

Comment: *"Multiple users can draw and save it as jpeg."*  Use PNG instead.  JPEG is lossy and every save will 'erode/dull' the quality further.

Comment: The combination of sockets, multiple users and applets mean this applet will probably need to be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Blank canvas is saved because `massDraw()` is never called, especially it's not called when you invoke `canvas.paint(bufImage.createGraphics())` in `saveJpegOP`.

`paint()` basically **redraws entire component** and since you decided not to override it (or `paintComponent()`), `drawMass()` is never called and empty canvas is painted.

So you need to override `paintComponent()` and call `massDraw()` with appropriate parameters. The parameter values can be, for instance, earlier set as properties in the `Canvas` class.